# Change Font from returne value of UDF in VBA using Range.Characters property

Tags: excel, vba, fonts, return-value, user-defined-functions

I've written a user defined function and want to change the font format of a defined character range, of the return value.

It doesn´t seem to work the way i expekt, for cells with functions "= ..." .
I only got 2 scenarios, first formated the whole return value and second doesn't format anything.
For "normal" cells, is works, as you can see in the screenshot.

try to change font format of first char to purple: top cell with function, botton cell without function:
[image: before]

Anyone have an idea, how to do it correctly?

Iam thankful about every answer / hint i can get!
Greetings Leo

Edit 03.12.2020 Thank you for all your answers and hints, some of you asked for code, here it is:

```
Public Function format(val As String)

With Application.Caller
 .Characters(1, 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 255)
End With

With Application.Caller.Offset(1, 0)
 .Characters(1, 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 255)
End With

format = val

End Function
```

So if you type some chars manually under the "function cell", for example "abcd", you should get following result (screenshot)

Top before running function, bottom after running function:
[image: after]

Comment: we need to see the code and how you are calling it.

Comment: Highly doubt this is possible based on your description, but please [edit] your question with your code.

Comment: No, it's impossible. **[Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/function-statement)** can return only *"...Byte, Boolean, Integer, Long, Currency, Single, Double, Decimal (not currently supported), Date, String (except fixed length), Object, Variant, or any user-defined type"* - there no "formatted text".

Comment: 2 Reasons why that cannot work: UDFs cannot change cells they can **only** return a value. You cannot change the color of a part of a cell if the cell contains a formula.

Comment: User defined Function can not return formatted text. They may return any VBA-Datatype, like numerich values (double, single) or strings. Would be an Excel-Gadget to have something like html-coded return strings, that are visualised in the cell.

Comment: @weeedy This does not work with formulas (UDFs), because of the mentioned reasons above. You can only color cells partly if they contain static text. It is impossible to do if they contain formulas (restriction of Excel). • Never name your function `format` as this is a reserved word in Excel VBA. The function `Format()` already exists in Excel!