# Change Font from return value of UDF in VBA using Range.Characters property

Tags: excel, vba, fonts, return-value, user-defined-functions

( [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65110841/change-font-from-returne-value-of-udf-in-vba-using-range-characters-property#comment115110553_65110841) )
Hello everyone,
I've written a user defined function and want to change the font format of a defined character range, of the return value.

It doesn´t seem to work the way i expekt, for cells with functions "= ..." . I only got 2 scenarios, first formated the whole return value and second doesn't format anything. For "normal" cells, is works, as you can see in the screenshot.

[try to change font format of first char to purple: top cell with function, botton cell without function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65110841/change-font-from-returne-value-of-udf-in-vba-using-range-characters-property#comment115110553_65110841)

Anyone have an idea, how to do it correctly?

Iam thankful about every answer / hint i can get! Greetings Leo

Edit 03.12.2020: Thank you for all your answers and hints, some of you asked for code, here it is:

```
Public Function format(val As String)

With Application.Caller
 .Characters(1, 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 255)
End With

With Application.Caller.Offset(1, 0)
 .Characters(1, 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 255)
End With

format = val

End Function
```

So if you type some chars manually under the "function cell", for example "abcd", you should get following result (screenshot) [top before running function, bottom after running function][2]

Greetings Leo [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65110841/change-font-from-returne-value-of-udf-in-vba-using-range-characters-property#comment115110553_65110841): https://i.stack.imgur.com/kh9AG.png [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGIXD.png

Comment: I get pink "abcd" in both cells.

Comment: Thank you for your response! So in both, one with the function return value, and the other without function, just manually typed in abcd ... Interesting, I don't know the reason. But eben if I would, it wouldn't be a solution for my problem ^^